# PTVS 2.1 with Python 3.5 not working with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, anaconda, python-3.5, ptvs

I'm using VS2010 (outdated, but it's what my office uses) I installed PTVS 2.1. Then I chose to install Anaconda, as suggested in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_okUV47eM5c&list=PLReL099Y5nRdLgGAdrb_YeTdEnd23s6Ff&index=1 I selected and installed python 3.5 from the Anaconda website

When I try create a project using existing files, it does that, but when I open the .pyproj, it says unsupported version 3.5.

Also, I am unable to refresh my DB(it says completion db needs refresh) in the Python environments window. I'm presuming the former is happening because of the latter. Please do let me know what to do.

Comment: Update. Not able to create new Application either says unsupported version 3.5 again.

Answer (score 1):

I also met this problem, and the environment is just like yours: VS 2010 with PTVS 2.1 and Anaconda 3. It seems that PTVS abandoned the support for old platforms, because Anaconda 2 works under the same circumstance.

Comment: Yes I felt so too.
So, I removed Anaconda and used the Python 2.6 from the company website and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.5 support was added in PTVS 2.2, which requires VS 2013 or later.

Unfortunately, "abandoning" earlier platforms is a necessity to keep improving the product, otherwise all engineering resources have to be directed to managing a huge test matrix. The source for PTVS is available and it is not difficult to build, so you can do it yourself. Or if that isn't a possibility, you could contact python@microsoft.com to ask about arranging a specific contract for backporting certain features.